# Group By, Agg, Reset Index where filter returns null continued

Tags: python, pandas

Here is something that would be a sample data set

```
 customer_number ethnicity fiscal_quarter  fiscal_year
1              231     Black      Quarter 1         2016
2              451     White      Quarter 1         2016
3              345     White      Quarter 1         2016
```

I would like to do the check for 'Asian' test on the ethnicity column, group by fiscal_year, fiscal_quarter, and count unique customer_number. But if there is no result for 'Asian', return a dataframe like below.

```
 customer_number fiscal_quarter  fiscal_year
1                0      Quarter 1         2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***short answer***

```
# make column `Categorical`, include `'Asian'` as one of the categories
e = df.ethnicity
df['ethnicity'] = pd.Categorical(e, categories=np.append('Asian', e.unique()))

# simple function to be applied.  performs 2nd level of `groupby`
def f(df):
    s = df.groupby('ethnicity').customer_number.nunique()
    return s.loc['Asian']

# initial `groupby`
d = df.groupby(['fiscal_year', 'fiscal_quarter']).apply(f)

d.reset_index(name='nunique')

   fiscal_year fiscal_quarter  nunique
0         2016      Quarter 1        0
```

---

***explanation***

- a convenient way to to `groupby` and produce aggregated results over `groups` that didn't exist, is to define the column of groups as `'Categorical'` where you define the categories to include the thing that is missing.  `pandas` will include that category in the aggregated results.
- However, in this case, I could not `groupby` with 3 different columns and maintain that same convenience.  I had to break up the grouping into 2.

  1. `groupby` columns that aren't `'Categorical'`.  Namely `['fiscal_year', 'fiscal_quarter']`
  2. `apply` to `groupby` in step 1, a function that performs a simple `groupby` over just `ethnicity`.  This ***will*** maintain the desired behavior and report on all categories regardless of whether they are represented in the data.

---

***leaving all categories***

```
e = df.ethnicity
df['ethnicity'] = pd.Categorical(
    e, categories=np.append(['Asian', 'Hispanic'], e.unique()))

def f(df):
    return df.groupby('ethnicity').customer_number.nunique()

d = df.groupby(['fiscal_year', 'fiscal_quarter']).apply(f)

d.stack().reset_index(name='nunique')

   fiscal_year fiscal_quarter ethnicity  nunique
0         2016      Quarter 1     Asian        0
1         2016      Quarter 1  Hispanic        0
2         2016      Quarter 1     Black        1
3         2016      Quarter 1     White        1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, the following should do:

```
import pandas as pd

# Generate data
d = {'customer_number': [231, 451, 345, 236, 457, 354],
'ethnicity': ['Black', 'White', 'White', 'Black', 'White', 'White'],
'fiscal_quarter': ['Quarter 1','Quarter 1','Quarter 1','Quarter 3','Quarter 3','Quarter 1'],
'fiscal_year': [2016, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2017]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Helper function to determine subset of
# dataframe that meets ethnicity condition
def find_ethnicity(dff, ethnicity):
    count = dff.customer_number[dff.ethnicity.eq(ethnicity)].nunique()
    if count == 0:
        dff = dff.head(1).copy()
    else:
        dff = dff[dff.ethnicity.eq(ethnicity)].copy().head(1)
    dff['ethnicity'] = ethnicity
    dff['customer_number'] = count
    return dff


# Test with ethnicity 'Black' grouping by fiscal_year and fiscal_quarter
print(df.groupby(['fiscal_year', 'fiscal_quarter'], as_index=False).apply(find_ethnicity, 'Black')).reset_index(drop=True)

#    customer_number ethnicity fiscal_quarter  fiscal_year
# 0                1     Black      Quarter 3         2015
# 1                1     Black      Quarter 1         2016
# 2                0     Black      Quarter 1         2017

# Test with ethnicity 'Asian' grouping by fiscal_year and fiscal_quarter
print(df.groupby(['fiscal_year', 'fiscal_quarter'], as_index=False).apply(find_ethnicity, 'Asian')).reset_index(drop=True)

#    customer_number ethnicity fiscal_quarter  fiscal_year
# 0                0     Asian      Quarter 3         2015
# 1                0     Asian      Quarter 1         2016
# 2                0     Asian      Quarter 1         2017

# Test with ethnicity 'White' grouping by fiscal_year and fiscal_quarter
print(df.groupby(['fiscal_year', 'fiscal_quarter'], as_index=False).apply(find_ethnicity, 'White')).reset_index(drop=True)

#    customer_number ethnicity fiscal_quarter  fiscal_year
# 0                1     White      Quarter 3         2015
# 1                2     White      Quarter 1         2016
# 2                1     White      Quarter 1         2017

# Test with ethnicity 'Latino' grouping by fiscal_year and fiscal_quarter
print(df.groupby(['fiscal_year', 'fiscal_quarter'], as_index=False).apply(find_ethnicity, 'Latino')).reset_index(drop=True)

#    customer_number ethnicity fiscal_quarter  fiscal_year
# 0                0    Latino      Quarter 3         2015
# 1                0    Latino      Quarter 1         2016
# 2                0    Latino      Quarter 1         2017

# Test with ethnicity 'Asian' without grouping
print(find_ethnicity(df, 'Asian'))

#    customer_number ethnicity fiscal_quarter  fiscal_year
# 0                0     Asian      Quarter 1         2016
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: I am very bad at the formatting of my questions on here at the moment. Sorry. Very new to Stack.

Comment: So it looks like you edited the def part of your code to count unique, and handle if no results? Correct?

Comment: Yup. Does the new definition help at all?